# Why can't I explicitly `-I /usr/include`?

Tags: gcc, include, clang

Both gcc and clang seem to silently discard `/usr/include` from the list of include directories when explicitly included via `-I`.
Is there a specific reason as to why common compilers apparently don't allow to include the system's include dir?

---

*background:*

Suppose you depend on a header file located in `/usr/include` while having inherited a directory containing an incompatible version of the same header from your build system via the `CPATH` environment variable (effectively appending that directory to the `-I` list from the right).

Comment: Create a new directory, symlink the files you want there, and point -I at that new directory. This avoids side effects that you do not control.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC ignores `-I/usr/include` because it is a system header directory by default, and using `-I` would turn it into non-system header, leading to confusing behavior, particularly with system headers that are not entirely aligned with language standards.  (GCC gives system headers more latitude and suppresses warnings, for example.)

If you use `-isystem /usr/include`, then `/usr/include` moves to the front of the search list.  However, you will likely have to move the other default search path entries as well, to avoid breaking too many things.  `gcc -v` will print the entire search path.

Comment: But please don't use `-isystem /usr/include`. The system headers are searched in a very specific order, and changing that order will break things.

Comment: Good point, it will likely be necessary to move the other default search paths as well.

Comment: `-isystem` wouldn't be able to override `CPATH` anyway since it has lower precedence than `CPATH` (which effectively is equivalent to `-I`).

Comment: `-nostdinc` could help, though that's going to be a fragile hack.